# Python Function to split one-item list into multi-item list based on number in string

Tags: python, list, split, list-comprehension

I have this 1-item list

```
['1Mike TroutLAA2Byron BuxtonMIN3Yermin MercedesCHW4Jesse WinkerCIN5Jared WalshLAA6Xander BogaertsBOS7J.D. MartinezBOS8Vladimir Guerrero Jr.TOR9Justin TurnerLAD0Ronald Acuna Jr.ATLNick CastellanosCIN2Michael BrantleyHOU3Austin RileyATL4Yuli GurrielHOU5Kris BryantCHC6Nelson CruzMIN7Cedric MullinsBAL8Raimel TapiaCOL9Brandon NimmoNYM20Bryce HarperPHI2Corey DickersonMIA22Luis RobertCHW23Matt OlsonOAK24Yordan AlvarezHOU24Nick MadrigalCHW26J.T. RealmutoPHI27Trea TurnerWSH28Alex VerdugoBOS29Eric HosmerSD30David PeraltaARI3Randal GrichukTOR32Jesus AguilarMIA33Adam FrazierPIT34Nick SolakTEX35Luis ArraezMIN36Joey WendleTB37C.J. CronCOL38Colin MoranPIT39Tommy EdmanSTL40Alex BregmanHOU40Bryan ReynoldsPIT42Trevor StoryCOL43Carlos CorreaHOU44Rafael DeversBOS45Aaron JudgeNYY46Carlos SantanaKC46Jose RamirezCLE48Franmil ReyesCLE49Jeimer CandelarioDET50Isiah Kiner-FalefaTEX']
```

I want to convert it into a 50-item list, with the separation being at each number.

So I would like to end up with something like:

```
['1Mike TroutLAA' , '2Byron BuxtonMIN', '3Yermin MercedesCHW', '4Jesse WinkerCIN' .........]
```

I know there is probably a list comprehension solution that somebody can answer pretty quickly. Thanks for reading

Answer (score 1):

You could use `re.findall` here:

```py
inp = '1Mike TroutLAA2Byron BuxtonMIN3Yermin MercedesCHW4Jesse WinkerCIN5Jared WalshLAA6Xander BogaertsBOS7J.D. MartinezBOS8Vladimir Guerrero Jr.TOR9Justin TurnerLAD0Ronald Acuna Jr.ATLNick CastellanosCIN2Michael BrantleyHOU3Austin RileyATL4Yuli GurrielHOU5Kris BryantCHC6Nelson CruzMIN7Cedric MullinsBAL8Raimel TapiaCOL9Brandon NimmoNYM20Bryce HarperPHI2Corey DickersonMIA22Luis RobertCHW23Matt OlsonOAK24Yordan AlvarezHOU24Nick MadrigalCHW26J.T. RealmutoPHI27Trea TurnerWSH28Alex VerdugoBOS29Eric HosmerSD30David PeraltaARI3Randal GrichukTOR32Jesus AguilarMIA33Adam FrazierPIT34Nick SolakTEX35Luis ArraezMIN36Joey WendleTB37C.J. CronCOL38Colin MoranPIT39Tommy EdmanSTL40Alex BregmanHOU40Bryan ReynoldsPIT42Trevor StoryCOL43Carlos CorreaHOU44Rafael DeversBOS45Aaron JudgeNYY46Carlos SantanaKC46Jose RamirezCLE48Franmil ReyesCLE49Jeimer CandelarioDET50Isiah Kiner-FalefaTEX'
output = re.findall(r'\d+.*?(?=\d+|$)', inp)
print(output)
```

This prints:

```
['1Mike TroutLAA', '2Byron BuxtonMIN', '3Yermin MercedesCHW', '4Jesse WinkerCIN',
 ...
 '49Jeimer CandelarioDET', '50Isiah Kiner-FalefaTEX']
```

Comment: You forgot to `import re`

Comment: @D4NieLDev Typically we don't show import statements in answers, as it obvious to anyone with Python experience that `re.findall` requires the regex library.

Comment: thanks for the reply. Your answer was very clear and concise. Explanation of import re should not be required for most, but if it helps somebody then thats good.